# Link de routeo en react no me cambia contenido de la pantalla

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap, react-router-dom

me está pasando esto:

Estoy aprendiendo react y estoy en la parte de routeo. Al tocar el "productos", del menú del navbar no me cambia el contenido hasta que refresco la página, lo mismo me pasa con inicio, lo que me sorprende es que parece que todo está ubicado como tiene que ser, porque cuando refresco aparece como debería. Que puede ser?

Este es el codigo de mi App.js

```
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from './components/navbar/NavBar';
import ItemListContainer from './container/ItemListContainer';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>

        <Route path="/productos">
          <ItemListContainer mensaje={"hola"} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/Ecommerce' >
          <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Este seria el inicio </h1>
        </Route>

      </Switch>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Y esta la navbar, hecha con bootstrap.

````
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap"
import CartIcon from './cartWidget'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './navBar.css'

const NavBar = () => {
    return <>
        <div>
            <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
                <Container>
                    <CartIcon className="cart-widget__icon" />
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Golden Byte</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Link to="/Ecommerce"><Nav.Link href="#home">Inicio</Nav.Link></Link>    
                        <Link to="/productos"><Nav.Link href="#features">Productos</Nav.Link></Link>   
                        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Proximamente</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    </>
}

export default NavBar```

Gracias de antemano
````